# Server Side Rendering failed: ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: msal.js

Any way to configure msal-angular to allow for server side rendering? I suspect this is due to a call with window which is not compatible with node on the server side. This error happens whenever I set the msalinterceptor. I am getting the following error when attempting to do this:

> ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
> at AuthCache.BrowserStorage

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MSAL Angular v1 does not support server-side rendering (i.e. Angular Universal). This will be supported in MSAL Angular v2, which we are working on now.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Jason. Any idea how far out the release will be?